# Difference between Braintree Customer and Submerchant?

Tags: payment, braintree

I've been reading through Braintree's documentation but I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out the difference between creating a customer:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+php/reference/request/customer/create

and creating a SubMerchant account:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+php/reference/request/merchant-account/create

Can anyone help explain what situations would call for you to use one over the other?

Comment: The [processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more help, please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Customers are your customers -- people who are paying you with credit cards / PayPal / etc.

Sub merchants are different -- they're other people / organizations on who's behalf you are accepting payments using Braintree. They're a feature of Braintree's [Marketplace](https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/marketplace) offering. If you're not a marketplace merchant, you don't need to worry about creating sub merchant accounts.